# Help with Linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq

I'm writing a linq query and I've run into trouble with it so I was wondering if someone could help. Here is a bit of background:

I didn't design the database so the structure cannot be changed. So I have the Main 'Game' table, which has a main product code, A foreign key in this table is GameDataID from the GameData table which contains information such as release dates, released by, etc. Then I have the GameFormat table, which contains the product codes for the game in each format, e.g. Mac, Windows, etc and again the GameDataID is a foreign key. See Below.

```
Game

GameID PK
MainGameProductCode
MainGameTitle
GameDataID FK

GameData

GameDataID PK
GameReleaseDate
GameReleasedBy

GameFormat

GameFormatID PK
GameDataID FK
GameFormatProductcode
```

So when sales reports are received back, some only contain 'GameFormatProductCode' as the product identifier. So from 'GameFormatProductCode' I need to retrieve the 'GameID' in the main Game table.

So far I have written the linq query to retrieve the GameFormatProductcode from the GameFormat table, however I am unsure how to go about retrieving the GameID from the main Game table.

```
private Int64 GetGameID(string gameFormatProductCode)
{
    ModelCtn ctn = new ModelCtn();
    Game game = null;
    GameFormat gf = null;

    gf = (from t in ctn.GameFormat
        where t.GameFormatProductcode == gameFormatProductCode
        select t).FirstOrDefault();

    // Need to find GameID from Game table and return it.

    return gf;

}
```

Any linq experts out there care to point me in the right direction? Very new to Linq so be gentle :)

Comment: I don't see relation between GameFormat and Game tables, do you have it?

Comment: Apologies, I have edited my question. GameDataID is a primary key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the `GameDataID` from the `GameFormat` table and use it to query the `Game` table

```
private Int64 GetGameID(string gameFormatProductCode)
{
    ModelCtn ctn = new ModelCtn();
    Game game = null;
    GameFormat gf = null;

    gf = (from t in ctn.GameFormat
        where t.GameFormatProductcode == gameFormatProductCode
        select t).FirstOrDefault();

    // Need to find GameID from Game table and return it.
    var gID = (from t in ctn.Game
               where t.GameDataID == gf.GameDataID
               select t.GameID).FirstOrDefault();

    return gID;

}
```

Comment: Thanks Geoff, Just one of those days!! I'll mark as correct when the time limit is up :)

Comment: This assumes that the Game.GameDataId has a 1 to 1 relationship with GameData.GameDataId... @109221793 is that correct?

Comment: I think it's better to replace the first `.FirstOrDefault()` call with a `.Single()` call, because otherwise the `where t.GameDataID == gf.GameDataID` could cause a `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I see it being possible is if there is a one to one relationship connecting Games and GameData tables.  If Game.GameDataID can only use a GameDataID once (and only once) then this should work.  If a GameData record can be used by multiple Games then this method will not be usable.

```
gf = (from t in ctn.GameFormat
     join g in ctn.Game on t.Game equals gd.GameDataID
     where t.GameFormatProductcode == gameFormatProductCode
     select g.GameID).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `GameDataId` from `GameFormat` could be used to find the `GameID` from the `Game` table.

EDIT:
Way too slow! Good answer by Geoff.